# Add images on wxComboBox (wx.python)

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm making a currency-converter and I want my coin-choice box (Dropdown box) to have mini-flags of each country (images) before the name of the country.

Does anybody know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried yourself. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Made question a littler clearer and cleaned up language.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wxpython Phoenix (that is, version 3 and above), you can use [BitmapComboBox](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.BitmapComboBox.html#wx-adv-bitmapcombobox) from the collection of advanced widgets.